# Where can I get free Vista style developer graphics?

Tags: winforms, graphics

What is the best source of free Vista style graphics for application development?  I want **32x32** and **16x16** that I can use in a Winforms application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio Professional or above, you've got a zip file of icons in your VS path under `Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary`. Some of the images use the Vista style.

Answer (score 3):

Best place I've found for commercial toolbar icons etc is [glyfx.com](http://glyfx.com).

Answer (score 2):

The [Tango project](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project) has some good icons

For areas that only need **16x16**, the silk icons from [famfamfam](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/) are good too

Both are Creative Commons licensed